# Draw diagram for k-means clustering with small-value data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-visualization

I am following this example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html

Everything works just fine except one thing that my data has small values.

The problem is in these two lines of code:

```
x_min, x_max = reduced_data[:, 0].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = reduced_data[:, 1].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 1].max() + 1
```

[image]

As you can see, we cannot view the data because of the scale of the axis limits.

If I change the code to:

```
x_min, x_max = reduced_data[:, 0].min(), reduced_data[:, 0].max()
y_min, y_max = reduced_data[:, 1].min(), reduced_data[:, 1].max()
```

Then I will get this graph and this warning:

[image]

```
UserWarning: Attempting to set identical bottom==top results
in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
bottom=-0.00239291040961, top=-0.00239291040961
```

Is there a way that I could tackle this problem except scaling up my data?

Here is my data:

```
[[ -1.96351038e-03  -1.92731612e-04]
 [  1.31726468e-03  -9.24830509e-04]
 [ -1.56064762e-03   7.29094485e-05]
 ...   
 [ -6.61219749e-04  -5.99944942e-04]
 [ -9.07169422e-04  -1.15375494e-04]
 [ -6.19167821e-04   6.17916959e-04]]
```

Comment: The warning basically says the difference between your `min()` and `max()` is [too small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) which become the same, which is an invalid axis scale. This is not the case with the scikit-learn example you referred. I guess you might want to share with us your data before we can provide any suggestions.

Comment: @Y.Luo updated...

Comment: Sorry that I'm not being clear before. What I really mean is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be helpful if we could understand why the difference within your data is so small. What you need here, at least in my opinion, is a way to scale your data. If you did `scale()` like the scikit-learn example you referred, you shouldn't have the problem. Apparently, you did something different which is important to answer your question yet we don't know. So what is that and why you cannot scale your data?

Comment: At first, I want the users are still able to read the original value from the axes.

I will scale my data if there is no way to address this problem.

Thank you so much for your help @Y.Luo